# How to use dialogs in a MasterDetail android application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I've been following the android developer guide, (specifically the [Passing events back to the dialog's host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)) to create a `DialogFragment` that will contain an `EditText` and pass back that text.
I want my `DetailFragment` to call that Dialog with a button press, but implementing my `DialogListener` on the fragment is not enough, it must be implemented on the activity, but from the `DetailActivity` I can't call my button's `OnClick` (button is on the fragment).

So my `DialogListener` must be implemented on the activity, but from there I can't get to my buttons, which are on the fragment.
Do my buttons just have to be on the `DetailActivity` instead of on the fragment for this to work? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: "but from there I can't get to my buttons, which are on the fragment" what do you need the buttons for at this point?

Comment: The button click is what will trigger the `dialog.show()` method.

Comment: I know that but what do you need the buttons for after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

you need to send a message to the activity when the button is clicked, then let the activity popup the dialog

Comment: So I need to implement the dialog.show() in both the `ListActivity` and the `DetailActivity` ? As both can contain my fragment?

Comment: fragments should not know another fragment exists. all fragment displaying happens from an activity so any dialogfragment that you need should be created in an activity

Comment: I also ended up moving my buttons from the fragment to the activity, just made the whole thing easier to manage.